# How to enter DOB randomly for each row in a table in in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

Error
SQL query:

```
UPDATE  `wfg_db`.`employee` SET  `DOB` = 
   (DECLARE@mm INT 
    DECLARE@xm INT 
    SET @mm =1 
    SET @xm =13 
    DECLARE@md 
    INT DECLARE@xd 
    INT SET @md =1 
    SET @xd =29 
    DECLARE@my INT 
    DECLARE@xy INT 
    SET @my =1900 
    SET @xy =2009 SELECT CAST( CAST( (

@xm - @mm
) * RAND( ) + @mm AS INT ) AS VARCHAR( 2 ) ) +  '/' + CAST( CAST( (
@xd - @md
) * RAND( ) + @md AS INT ) AS VARCHAR( 2 ) ) +  '/' + CAST( CAST( (
@xy - @my
) * RAND( ) + @my AS INT ) AS VARCHAR( 4 ) ) AS DATE ) 
WHERE  `employee`.`id`
```

MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DECLARE @mm int DECLARE @xm int
>   SET @mm = 1 SET @xm = 13 DECLARE @md int ' at line 1

Comment: What are you trying to do with this SQL?

Comment: Could you rearrange the statement a little to make it easier to understand, please? When you've done that, you may well see the problem yourself. Syntax errors lurk in untidy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
 UPDATE  `wfg_db`.`employee` SET  `DOB` = 
   cast(ADDDATE('1900-01-01',rand()*40176) as date)
   /*    WHERE  `employee`.`id` = What?*/
```

Comment: i want to restrict the random values between 1900 to 1985 only
wht modification required?

Comment: Change the number to 31411 from 40176

Comment: I have no idea what that comment is meant to mean!

Comment: date of birth goes into the future
like 12/2/2029
whts this?

Comment: No idea. Are you sure you're using `cast(ADDDATE('1900-01-01', rand()*31411) as date)`?

Comment: yup i m usin d same but it genarates future dates...:(

Comment: Well it definitely shouldn't do and doesn't for me.